# Missing Dictation Scenario for Microsoft Custom Speech Service

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-speech-platform

Why is there is no dictation scenario and only a conversation scenario on cris.ai?  My users need to be able to dictate punctuation and the conversation scenario does not handle this.  It was supported in the past but is no longer there.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speech team responded to me over email and said to change over to a different endpoint which supports dictation.  Their response was as follows:

You can set up dictation mode with the SDK when you create an instance of the SpeechFactory.

Instead of using method FromSubscription() i.e.

```
var factory = SpeechFactory.FromSubscription("YourSubscriptionKey", "YourServiceRegion");
```

use fromEndpoint() like this

```
var factory = SpeechFactory.FromEndpoint("wss://westus.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/dictation/cognitiveservices/v1", "YourKey");
```